# Adding a dot product (thus a scalar) to the zero vector

Tags: vectors, geometry

Please consider the following calculation:

`A` and `B` are vectors (*not* their magnitudes).
$\vec{0}$ is the *0 vector* (not the scalar).

The calculation:

$$(A dot B) + \vec{0}$$

Is this calculation valid? If so, what does it yield?

`(A dot B)` of course gives a scalar. However, we cannot add a scalar to a vector.

Comment: this belongs to [math.se]

Comment: In a vector space, it is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course no, a scalar product (or dot product) in a (real) vector space $V$ is a symmetric bilinear form
$$
g : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}
$$
which is also positive definite. Id est $g(v,v) \geq 0$ and $g(v,v) = 0$ if and only if $v \in V$ is the zero vector.
Therefore, it makes no sense to sum the dot product of two vectors (which is a scalar) with a vector.